# PHP - MySQL find row and replace

Tags: php, mysql

what im trying to figure out is how do i find something in my MySQL database and then replacing another row. Example

```
  mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
  VALUES ('$_POST[custom]', '$_POST[receiver_email]','$_POST[mc_gross]')");

  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons
  WHERE FirstName='bjarne'");
  mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO persons (LastName)
  VALUES ('$_POST[item_name]')");
```

Here i would like it to find where `FirstName` is "`bjarne`" and then replace his `LastName` with `'$_POST[item_name]'` in this case.

Comment: update table set LastName = '$_POST[item_name]' where FirstName = 'bjarne'

Comment: 1990 called, they want their SQL injection back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `Persons` SET `LastName`='".$_POST['item_name']."'
WHERE `FirstName`='bjarne'");
```